# Running all possible fixed effects combinations for linear mixed effects models

Tags: r, lme4

I am interested in running all possible models for different linear mixed models and then comparing them. For example, the whole model, including every possible fixed factor would be:

```r
control_bag1 <- lmer(mn$perc.bag1 ~ mn$snail.density + 
    mn$live.biomass + mn$detritivore.total + mn$bag1_percnit + 
    mn$avg.delta.rh + mn$NH4 + (1|mn$year) + (1|mn$block), 
     REML = TRUE)
```

How could a `for` loop be designed to test every possible fixed factor combination? I know this is a lot of fixed factors, I will be refining my predictions but how could I do this in theory?

Answer (score 1):

- **tl;dr** `MuMin::dredge(full_model)`. This won't by default give you all the model object themselves - just a table with coefficients, AIC values, etc. - but the "Details" section of `?dredge` tells you how to get the fitted models themselves, if that's what you need.
- you're right that this is usually a bad idea. You could ask a question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) explaining your ultimate goal (i.e., what you're trying to achieve by fitting all subsets) and might get useful answers about a better strategy to achieve the goal.
- it's general a bad idea to use `data$` in formulas: instead, express your model as

```r
lmer(perc.bag1 ~ snail.density + live.biomass + detritivore.total + ...
```

This will allow downstream methods like `predict` to work better.